# Displaying data from two tables using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to display data from two tables from phpMyadmin database.
I have a website with a form where you put what information are you looking for and then this information should be displayed from two tables in the database. I know I have to use a SQL JOIN, I have tried different ways and cannot figure this out. I will appreciate any help

Here is my php code:

```
    <?php
//connect to database:
$con = mysql_connect("SERVER", "LOGIN", "PASS") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("TABLE", $con) or die ("Connection Failed");

//create a PHP variable to hold the value from HTML form
$from = $_POST['arrival'];
$to = $_POST['destination'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$tailnumber = $_POST['tailnumber'];

$error_status = false;

// validating input
if (empty($_POST['arrival'])){
echo "Please enter the origin.";
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($_POST['destination'])){
echo "</br></br> Please enter the destination.";
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($_POST['time'])){
echo "</br></br> Please enter the date.";
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($_POST['tailnumber'])){
echo "</br></br> Please enter the tail number.";
$error_status = true;
} 

//create the query for selecting all the records which equal to the value from the form
if(!$error_status) {
$query = "SELECT *
FROM INBOUND_FLIGHT
INNER JOIN OUTBOUND_FLIGHT 
ON INBOUND_FLIGHT.TAIL_NUMBER = OUTBOUND_FLIGHT.TAIL_NUMBER
WHERE INBOUND_FLIGHT.ARRIVAL_TIME = '$time' AND INBOUND_FLIGHT.TAIL_NUMBER = '$tailnumber' AND INBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_FROM = '$from'AND OUTBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_TO = '$to'";

//run query
$result = mysql_query($query);
// creating a table
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ARRIVAL TIME</th>
<th>AIRCRAFT TYPE</th>
<th>TAIL NUMBER</th>
<th>CREW NAME</th>
<th>ORIGIN</th>
<th>DESTINATION</th>
</tr>";

//Print the record that matches the criteria of the query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['INBOUND_FLIGHT.ARRIVAL_TIME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['INBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_TYPE' ] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['INBOUND_FLIGHT.TAIL_NUMBER'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['INBOUND_FLIGHT.CREW_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['INBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_FROM'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['OUTBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_TO'] . "</td>";
}}
//close the connection
mysql_close($con);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

I used

```
SELECT *
FROM INBOUND_FLIGHT, OUTBOUND_FLIGHT
...
```

and then changed the echo display

```
echo "<td>" . $row['ARRIVAL_TIME'] . "</td>";
...
...
```

Comment: omg how stupid we are ....just a simple mistake and did not figured it out if you think our answer are helpful than you can upvote and you can accept correct anwer

Answer (score 0):

Put a space after `'$from'` in your query section below:

```
    AND INBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_FROM = '$from'AND
```

as

```
    AND INBOUND_FLIGHT.AIRCRAFT_FROM = '$from' AND
```

Comment: @Tomala: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Is it givings some error or you are getting different results than expected. Also what is the data type of `ARRIVAL_TIME` and what value your passing through $time?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. 
what I am getting is a blank table, no data in it, however there is data in the database to be displayed. 
I am passing "date" type through $time.
It used to be DATETIME, but I have changed it to be just DATE but I have not changed ARRIVAL_TIME to ARRIVAL_DATE yet. However I am typing "2012-11-13" in the ARRIVAL TIME form to get the information, so it works.